# Conver string (text) representation of 2 bytes to Integer

Tags: c, integer, byte

I have a 4 text-represented bytes that i need to divide into 2 bytes (HI and LO byte) and convert it to two integers.

How can i do that in plain C?

```
0x4b 0xab 0x14 0x9d
```

By text i mean that they look like "0x4b" not 0x4b.

I already have those string splited into char array, which represents like this:

```
item[0] = "0x4b";
item[1] = "0xab";
item[2] = "0x14";
item[3] = "0x9d";
```

Now the finish should look like this:

```
0x4b 0xab - one integer
0x14 0x9d - second integer
```

How to do this in Plain C?

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what exactly was the problem?

Comment: You are probably looking for [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol)

Comment: You write _"0x4b 0xab - one integer"_. What exactly is this supposed to mean? I see two integers there. Do you want to get this integer: `0x4bab`

Comment: I was able already to recover those values from UART /proc module but i cannot "find a way" to change this. Removing by text search "0x" doesnt look like good option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probbaly want this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char *item[4];
  item[0] = "0x4b";
  item[1] = "0xab";
  item[2] = "0x14";
  item[3] = "0x9d";

  int value1 = (strtol(item[0], NULL, 0) << 8) | strtol(item[1], NULL, 0);
  int value2 = (strtol(item[2], NULL, 0) << 8) | strtol(item[3], NULL, 0);

  printf("%x %x", value1, value2);
}
```

Comment: This is nice and compact! I am Up voting.

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach if you need intermediate results:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
  int item1[4];
  int item2[2];
  char *item[4];

  item[0] = "0x4b";
  item[1] = "0xab";
  item[2] = "0x14";
  item[3] = "0x9d";

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
     item1[i] = strtol ( item[i], NULL, 0  ) ;
     printf("%2X\n", item1[i]);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
      item2[2*i] = (item1[2*i] << 8) | item1[2*i+1]; 
      printf("Received integers: %2X\n", item2[2*i]);
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

Output:

```
4B                                                                                                                                 
AB                                                                                                                                 
14                                                                                                                                 
9D                                                                                                                                 
Received integers: 4BAB                                                                                                            
Received integers: 149D
```